# Why does devexpress gridview cell's value disappear after clicking outside the cell?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a gridview linking a stored procedure of database. I try to add some new columns to gridview. That's my C# code:

```
{
GridColumn column = gridView1.Columns.AddVisible(colName, colName);
gridView1.Columns[colName].VisibleIndex = position;
}
```

That work well. But when I focus on a gridColumn's cell for typing value (I can till type normally), then I click outside the cell, cell's value disappear. What's wrong with it?
Please help me, thank you so much.

Comment: Check the column's FieldName property. Does a corresponding column exists in the underlying DataSource?

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič Thank you for your interaction. I think FieldName prop is fine, because I have used a foreach to get every grid columns in list (gridview.Columns ) and I don't see any FieldNames overlapping.

Comment: Are you bound to a datatable or an object?  If it's an object, is that column bound to a property -- if not, add a property and bind it and see if the edited value changes the object property value or not.

Comment: Keep in mind also that the GridColumn.FieldName property is case-sensitive. It must exactly match the casing of the data source property to which it is bound.

Comment: @Hambone I bound to a stored procedure, I think it's a kind of datatable. Is that right?

Comment: @Brendon sorry but I can't understand what you say: It must exactly match the casing of the data source property to which it is bound. What do you mean?

Comment: What is the data source for your GridControl? If it was bound to a List<T> where T has a property called "FirstName", the First Name GridColumn's FieldName property must also be "FirstName". It cannot be "firstname" or "FIRSTNAME". It has to match the value of the property.

Comment: @Brendon I don't bind a data source to my GridControl programtically, I generated a Dataset linking my database and I drag and drop a mapping table of Dataset into my Winform. After that, I used above C# codes to add some new columns (these columns don't bind datatable) to gridview. I hoped that I can type value to the new column's cell, but the value just disappear after I click outside the cell.

Comment: Make sure the DataColumns in your DataTable aren't read-only.